# how to undo the publishing in to an azure web application

Tags: c#, azure, web-applications, publishing

I have created a web application on azure portal and published my code into it from visual studio. I want to undo the publishing. any suggestions?

Comment: restore a backup?

Comment: Delete the files that you deployed using Kudu or FTP

Answer (score 2):

Deployment slots is useful in following scenarios,

**`Staged Deployment`**

In staged deployment, we deploy a website to a non-production slot that is acting as the staged environment. In this environment, we can test whether the website is working as expected. If the website is working properly as expected we can swap the production slot with staging slot.

**`Incremental Deployment`**

It may be possible that some of the activities to be performed after deployment. In that, we can deploy the website on a non-production slot. We can make perform activity required post-deployment and then swap with the production slot to make the updated website live.

**`Rolling Back Deployment`**

If after swapping a non-production slot into production, you need to roll back the deployment, you can swap the production slot again with the slot that contains the previous production content and configuration, thereby rolling back the deployment.

[Reference link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-webapp-rollback-your-deployment-using-deployment-slot/)

Also Azure web app comes Backup feature too , which you can enable it your app and keep the backup of your site. When you feel that the deployment didn't go as expected, you can restore the backup .

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup

Hope it helps.

Comment: should be noted that all these features require at minimum a standard S1 App service plan which is a bit above ~50 bucks per month.